# Creating a chain between array elements

Tags: typescript

I have an array of about five articles. When they're displayed on the page, the user only sees one article at a time and can cycle between articles back and forth. I want the articles to be chained together, so that when a user cycles between articles, I can simply do `currentArticle = currentArticle.nextArticle;` or `currentArticle = currentArticle.prevArticle;` and it would work just fine.

In the end, it would look like this:

```
+---------+--------------+------------------+
| Article | Next Article | Previous Article |
+---------+--------------+------------------+
| 1       | 2            | 5                |
| 2       | 3            | 1                |
| 3       | 4            | 2                |
| 4       | 5            | 3                |
| 5       | 1            | 4                |
+---------+--------------+------------------+
```

Here is the interface I want to use:

```
export interface Article {
    title: string
    content: string

    nextArticle: Article | null
    prevArticle: Article | null
}
```

I already figured out a solution, but it seems like overkill, so I was wondering if there is a better, more elegant solution. Basically, I numbered the articles in a new array (from 1 to n, in this case 5), iterate through all of them and use the current article number in combination with the total article count to directly grab the correct article using the number:

```
let articleCount = Object.keys(articleList).length;
let indexNext = 1;
let indexPrev = 1;

for (const [a, article] of Object.entries(articleList)) {
    indexNext = Number(a) + 1;
    indexPrev = Number(a) - 1;

    if(indexNext > articleCount) {
        indexNext = 1;
    }

    if(indexPrev === 0) {
        indexPrev = articleCount;
    }

    article.nextArticle = articleList[indexNext];
    article.prevArticle = articleList[indexPrev];
}
```

Is there a better way to chain objects like this? I'd be happy if I could cut down on a little code here.

In case you're wondering, the reason why the articles aren't indexed from the start is because they use a made up id for their key, which I want to keep the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach**

```js
let articles = Object.entries(articleList).map(([key, value]) => ({
 ...value,
 indexNext: Number(key) + 1,
 indexPrev: Number(key) - 1
}));
let articleCount = articles.length;

for (let article of articles) {
    let indexNext = article.indexNext;
    let indexPrev = article.indexPrev;

    if(indexNext > articleCount) {
        indexNext = 1;
    }

    if(!indexPrev) {
        indexPrev = articleCount;
    }

    article.nextArticle = articles[indexNext];
    article.prevArticle = articles[indexPrev];
}
```

***Second Approach***

```js
let articles = Object.values(articleList)
let articleCount = articles.length;

let mapArray = Array(articleCount).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({
 indexCurrent: index,
 indexNext: (index + 1) % articleCount,
 indexPrev: index - 1
}))
mapArray[0].indexPrev = articleCount - 1;

for (let {indexCurrent, indexPrev, indexNext} of mapArray) {
  let article = articles[indexCurrent];
  article.nextArticle = articles[indexNext];
  article.prevArticle = articles[indexPrev];
}
```

Looks to me you can either move computing of prev, next indicies in another section or put it inside the loop but chaining logic is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
const result = Object.values(articleList).map((article, index) => ({
    ...article,
    prevArticle: articleList[(articleList.length + index - 1) % articleList.length + 1],
    nextArticle: articleList[(index + 1) % articleList.length + 1],
}));
```

This assumes, that your indices are just starting at 1.